# Reading data from Cloud Storage using Flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am using a flutter web application `(.dart)`, the aim is to read data from the `Cloud Storage`. I tried this but I keep getting null.

```
loadFromStorage() async {
print("Calling cloud function...");
final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('/data/ecg/hp2-1B72D3/1584859928685.ecg').getData(100).then((data) =>
    setState(() {
      imageBytes = data.toString();
    })
);

print(imageBytes);
```

}

what is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is the method i use on web with package firebase

```
Future<String> uploadImage(
      {@required Uint8List imageData, @required String productId}) async {
//    print('FirebaseImageStorageRepositoryWeb.uploadImage() started');

    StorageReference ref = firebase.storage().ref('Products').child(productId);
    String imageUrl;
    await ref.put(imageData).future.whenComplete(() async {
      await ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) {
        imageUrl = url.toString();
//        print('image url is :$imageUrl');
        return;
      }).catchError((e) {
//        print('FirebaseImageStorageRepositoryWeb.uploadImage() error: $e');
      });
      return;
    });

    return imageUrl;
  }

  @override
  Future deleteImage({@required String productId}) async {
    StorageReference ref = firebase.storage().ref('Products').child(productId);


    ref.delete().whenComplete(() {
      return;
    }).catchError((e) {
      print('FirebaseImageStorageRepositoryWeb.deleteImage() error: $e');
    });
    return;
  }
```

And this is the device verision usin `firebase_storage`

```
  final picker = ImagePicker();
Future<String> uploadImage(
      {@required Uint8List imageData, @required String productId}) async {

//    print('FirebaseImageStorageRepositoryDevice.uploadImage() started');

    String imageUrl;
    await ref.child('Products').child(productId).putData(imageData).onComplete.whenComplete(() async {
//      print('FirebaseImageStorageRepositoryDevice.uploadImage() image uploaded');
      await ref.child('Products').child(productId).getDownloadURL().then((url) {
//        print('FirebaseImageStorageRepositoryDevice.uploadImage() getting imageUrl');
        imageUrl = url;
//        print('image url is :$imageUrl');
        return;
      }).catchError((e) {
//        print('FirebaseImageStorageRepositoryDevice.uploadImage() error: $e');
      });
      return;
    });

    return imageUrl;
  }
```

This should put you in the right direction